# Reference native dll not to the root of project

Tags: .net

To add native dll reference I have to add it to project as content and set Copy to Output to Always or Copy if Newer. But the problem for me is that I have to add all native dlls to the root of project to make them copied to the output folder.

I want to create a folder NativeReferences and put there all my native references. Unfortunately in this case native dlls are copied not to output/ but to output/NativeReferences/

Is there any way to group native dlls and move them away from the project root?

Comment: You could pinvoke SetDllDirectory() if you really want to.  Not so sure it is worth it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a post-build event in your project and do a 'normal' copy from some lib directory to the current output directory. That way you can put all native dlls in one directory, don't have to add them to the project itself and have full control over where they get copied.